# Why tensorflow may want to specify dynamic dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an existing complex model. Inside there is tensor `x` with shape (None, 128, 128, 3). First axis has dynamic shape, that should be materialized when batch is passed to `feed_dict` in `session.run`. However when I attempt to define broadcast operation to shape of x:

```
y = tf.broadcast_to(z, (x.shape[0], x.shape[1], x.shape[2], 1))
```

Exception is raised:

```
Failed to convert object of type <class 'tuple'> to 
Tensor. Contents: (Dimension(None), Dimension(128), 
Dimension(128), 1). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Exception occurs when creating model, not when running it. Converting first element to number helps, but this is not the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.shape` attribute gives you the shape known at graph construction time, which is a [`tf.TensorShape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape) structure. If the shape of `x` were fully known, you could get your code to work as follows:

```
y = tf.broadcast_to(z, (x.shape[0].value, x.shape[1].value, x.shape[2].value, 1))
```

However, in your case `x` has an unknown first dimension. In order to use the actual tensor shape as a regular [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor) (with value only known at runtime), you can use [`tf.shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape):

```
x_shape = tf.shape(x)
y = tf.broadcast_to(z, (x_shape[0], x_shape[1], x_shape[2], 1))
```